# mysql performance

Tags: mysql-5.5

Currently,we are using mysql 5.5.4 database on server with 4GB RAM,500GB HDD on Linux.There are predominantly 3 databases and the maximum size of database is 100MB.Assuming data grows at rate of x mb per day,how long can mysql be used without failover?When data scales,is it better to shift to Oracle or  postgreSQL?How can I measure performance and get threshold values for mysql performance?

Comment: 5.5.4 was pre-GA.  Not wise to keep running that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad, I'll try to give you some guidelines and tips.

Your databases are quite small, MySQL can handle databases much larger than that. I don't see the need to switch to another database.

You should also use a separate partition for the mysqldata directory so if the system partition fills up the database is still safe (and vice versa).

Use tools such as [Mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) to check if your MySQL config is correct with respect to your hardware. You can also do periodic benchmarks with [sysbench](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/sysbench.1.html) to ensure your server is working smoothly.

By the way, I'd recommend that you switch to MySQL 5.6 which is the latest stable version.

Comment: Do not just blindly follow what mysqltuner will tell you, it has some false alarms (table fragmentation and such).

Comment: As a general rule, you should never blindly do whatever *any* software tool tells you; take it into consideration and then take a decision based on your expertise.